# Long table in nature style using tabularx

Tags: tables, journal-publishing

I have a long table and I wrote using `tabularx` and my document class is `sn-nature`. Unfortunately, half of the table is hidden from the right side of the page. Moreover, I expect that the table can adaptively manage the required space that each row needs:

```
\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}

    
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} c @{}}
    \toprule
    \hline
    \centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
    \hline
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
        Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
        
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
        
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
        Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
        
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
    
        Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline
        
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ \hline

    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

It is worthy to mention that I receive the following error:
[image]

The following is the output:
[image]

Any idea?

Update1:
By trying the answer introduced by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , at the top of the table in the next pages the header and the caption is represented.

Update2:

Unfortunately the the information of the first two cells are mixed with each other and the texts are condensed. The code I used:

```
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Column (1) shows the model ...},
label={my-label}
]{
    colspec={ @{} X[halign=l] c X[2.1,halign=l] c c c @{} },
    row{1}={halign=c},
    rowhead = 1
}
\toprule
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
\midrule
Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE   \\ 
RA \cite{p} & 2020 & RGB Images, Optical Flow Map, Semantic Image & RNN & C3D & DR(eye)VE   \\ 
model2  \cite{p} & 2021 & RGB Video Frames, Semantic Images & CNN, GCN, ConvLSTM & Custom  & DADA, DR(eye)VE, TDV   \\ 
 
\bottomrule
 \end{longtblr}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to somehow define your `C` column type. Also why use `tabularx` if there is not a single `X` column in your table? You are also specifying way more columns than your table actually has.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , I reduced the number of columns to 6 but has not been fixed. How I can defice C . Could you please let me have your answer

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the `C` column type you use, which is not available by default and also not defined in your document.

Besides this error there are a couple of other problems:

- you are using a `tabularx` without a single `X` columns. Tabularx is can't adjust the width of your columns if you don't allow it to do so with a `X` column
- while the text in your columns is short, the words in your header row are long in comparison and increase the width of the columns. Not a pretty solution, but you can work around this by giving numbers or abbreviations in the header row and explain their meaning in the caption.
- your table is too long for a single page. A tabularx does not allow page breaks. I suggest to use a `longtblr` from the `tabularray` package instead.

---

```
\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
   caption = {Column (1) shows the model ...},
   label={my-label}
]{
  colspec={ @{} X[halign=l] c X[2.1,halign=l] c c c @{} },
  row{1}={halign=c},
  rowhead = 1
}
    \toprule
    (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
    \midrule
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    Multi-branch \cite{p} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, Optical Flow Maps, Semantic Images & CNN & C3D &  Dataset   \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How it is possible to avoid representation of the caption and the (1) , (2) ,... ,(6) at the top of each next pages. I updated the question by trying your answer.

Comment: @dtr43 Remove `rowhead = 1` if you don't like the repetition of the header, but are you sure that's a good idea? Your reader will have to track columns over multiple pages to see which column shows what.

Comment: Thanks for the point, what about the caption?

Comment: `\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}`

Comment: Unfortunately the elements of the last column mixes with the first column. I updated the question

Comment: @dtr43 Can't reproduce. You will need to show the code you used.

Comment: , I updated the question with the reproducible code.

Comment: @dtr43 As already stated in my answer, there is not enough space on your page to add very long words in the header row. Also if you start to add longer text in your columns, use an X column instead of c.